# How does the partner portal decide what server a test org is created on?

Tags: isv, org

I have created a few test orgs through the partner portal recently, and every single one is being spawned on ap1.

I am based in Australia so this makes sense, but in the past I have received orgs on na12, 7 14 11 9...

I like having orgs on different servers because it lets me be logged into each one simultaneously in the same browser.

Do I have any control over what server my test org is spawned on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the [My Domain feature](https://na6.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/domain_name_overview.htm) in each org you create, you can log into multiple orgs on the same pod. Since these are test orgs, use some sort of throw away naming convention. (verticalcoder-test1.my.salesforce.com, etc)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to specify which pod your org is created on.

One workaround for your simultaneous logins though is that you can use Chrome's incognito mode which will enable you to log into multiple orgs simultaneously, even if those orgs are in the same domain.

Comment: You can also use the My Domain feature to log into multiple orgs at once on the same pod, but make sure to use domain that are throw away since these are just test orgs.

Comment: @daniel that is a great answer, if you post it as one I will accept it